# Send an Email using PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, email, powerpoint, send

I want to send an email (with subject, body...) to another email address.
I tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ret As Boolean
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim strMessage As String

    strAddress = "examplemail@gmail.com"
    ret = SendEMail(strAddress, (Label1.Caption), strMessage)
    Label1.Caption = ret

    If Label1.Caption = "True" Then
        MsgBox "Mail sent!"
    ElseIf Label1.Caption = "False" Then
        MsgBox "Mail not sent!"
    End If

End Sub


Public Function SendEMail(strRecipient As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String) As Boolean

    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oMail As Object

    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next

    Set oApp = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Err.Clear
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
    With oMail
        .Subject = strSubject
        .To = strRecipient
        'copy to self
        .CC = "youraddy@you.com"
        .BodyFormat = 1
        .Body = strBody
        .Send
    End With

    'cleanup
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing

    'All OK?
    If Err = 0 Then SendEMail = True Else SendEMail = False

End Function
```

The code was originally taken from [here](http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/PowerPoint_Email.html).

If it is possible, I want a code that is compatible with most PCs.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Microsoft Outlook**
For sending an e-mail you need to have an e-mail account in Microsoft Outlook configured, because your code is using Outlook to send the e-mail.

> `Set oApp = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")`

---

**Alternative 1: SMTP**
Alternatively you could set up an SMTP connection in VBA to send the e-mails over an external mail server using CDO. More information on the usage of CDO in VBA can be found [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm) (even if they write the code is for Excel, you can use it for PowerPoint as well) and [here](https://www.devhut.net/2014/11/29/vba-cdo-mail/) as well.

The drawback of this approach is, that the SMTP login credentials are visible in the VBA code. This could be a security issue if you plan to share this presentation with other people.

---

**Alternative 2: Mailto-Link**
A third way would be to offer the user a link to click on in order to send the e-mail: `mailto:recipient@example.com?subject=xxx`
A description for this approach can be found [here](http://www.databison.com/3-nifty-ways-to-send-email-using-excel/) (scroll down to the third option).

Comment: I tryed now another code...
But I get an error: Run-yime error '-2147220978 (8004020e)'
And it also says that the sender's adress was rejected.

Comment: You should precisely specify what other code you have tried if you expect any help with it. Ideally, you would add it to your original question.

Comment: I tryed to past the code here, but ir's too long. It's the first big code [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm).

Comment: any help, pls??

Comment: The error you got was "the sender's address was rejected". Please check your SMTP settings in the code. Most probably you need to authenticate with your SMTP credentials on the mail server to send the email:     
`config.Fields(cdoSMTPAuthenticate).Value = cdoBasic`
`config.Fields(cdoSendUserName).Value = "youUserName"`
`config.Fields(cdoSendPassword).Value = "yourPassword"`
`config.Fields(cdoSMTPServerPort).Value = xxx`
`config.Fields(cdoSMTPUseSSL).Value = "true"`

Comment: I tried to add that code, but I get even more errors, like "Variable not set"... Now I'm really confused and can't do it. It would be much easier to give me the code with everything done to work...

Comment: I'm sorry, that is not the idea behind StackOverflow to develop code for other people. If you have some code, feel free to ask a question about it. Here you will find the guidelines for good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I put already too much effort into figuring out your problem. Please try to figure it out on your own. I've pasted you some sources about the CDO implementation: https://www.devhut.net/2014/11/29/vba-cdo-mail/, https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm, http://www.codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=1&targetDoc=email-versenden-access-vba-cdo

Comment: Anyway, I just found the right code on Youtube, it worked GREAT!

Comment: That sounds nice. Would you like to share that video here, that other people with a similar problem will find a solution as well?